# Change checkbox icon when checked Vuejs Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

So I am trying to check the checkbox Icon to something more custom, perhaps a different icon, however, I tried a couple different things like pseudo elements with no success.  right now what this does is loops through data and displays the name and when checked highlights it based on the css class.  What I am trying to do is when check change the checkbox icon.

css

```
.unchecked{
  color: gray;
}
.checked{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

Vuejs Component.

```
Vue.component('check-list', {
    template: `
            <v-container>
                <v-row >
                  <v-col >
                      <v-checkbox 
                        v-for="item in values" 
                        :key="item.id" 
                        :value="item.id" 
                         v-model="selected"
                        >
                       
                          <template v-slot:label>
                              <div :class="selected.includes(item.id) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'">
                               {{item.name}}
                              </div>
                          </template>
                          
                        </v-checkbox>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              <pre>{{selected}}</pre>
            </v-container>  
  `,
  data: function () {
    return {
     selected: [],
     values: [
                {id:'1',name:'Name 1'},
                {id:'2', name:'Name 2'},
                {id:'3', name:'Name 3'},
        ],   
     ex4: ['red']  
    }
  },
  methods: {
    
  },
})


new Vue({
  el: '#components-demo',
  vuetify: new Vuetify({
      icons: {
        iconfont: 'md',
    },
  }),
  data: () => ({
    
  }),
})
```

Comment: your issue in the class binding?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I think so?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim sorry, what I am trying to do is change the checkbox icon when checked.   The `:class` is working to change the background color of the div when checked.

Comment: you couldn't change the checkbox icon

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim or maybe like a custom checkmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@chewie, it is possible to change the checkbox icon in Vuetify, There is a specia prop to handle this

**:on-icon="'icon-name'"
:off-icon="'icon-name'"**

Please find the full code below

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container
      class="px-0"
      fluid
    >
      <v-row >
                  <v-col >
                      <v-checkbox
                        :on-icon="'mdi-heart'"
                        :off-icon="'mdi-home'"
                        v-for="item in values" 
                        :key="item.id" 
                        :value="item.id" 
                         v-model="selected"
                        >
                       
                          <template v-slot:label>
                              <div :class="selected.includes(item.id) ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'">
                               {{item.name}}
                              </div>
                          </template>
                          
                        </v-checkbox>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              <pre>{{selected}}</pre>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      selected: [],
     values: [
                {id:'1',name:'Name 1'},
                {id:'2', name:'Name 2'},
                {id:'3', name:'Name 3'},
        ],   
     ex4: ['red'] 
    }
  },
})
```

> Please find the working codepen here:
> https://codepen.io/chansv/pen/QWdEPvB?editors=1010

Comment: If I want to put an svg icon in local, how do you think I can do it?